# Where [if anywhere] should the apostrophe go in "three days work"?

Tags: grammar, apostrophe

Which is correct?

> 1 Three day's work
>
> 2 Three days' work
>
> 3 Three days work

I would probably guess (2) is right, since the work belongs to the three days ("three days *of* work"). But I'm not sure. Would it be different if it was only one day?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

"Three days' work" is correct.

Yes, it would be different if it was one day: "one day's work" refers to a single day, so *day* would not be plural to start with.

Comment: Seems odd to think about a the work BELONGING TO the day. How can a day have work? Maybe I'm over-thinking this one :-)

Comment: A day can have many things. It has a morning, an afternoon, an evening, a type of weather, and so on.

Comment: Perhaps a day's _worth_ of work might make more sense. But as in most cases, due to the lengthiness of phrases, we cut down on words cos other people understand us anyway ... :P

Comment: @Urbycoz - think of it as "work associated with a day" rather than "belonging to" if you like.

Comment: I'd probably choose the plural attributive in "He's got three days work next week" . We've had a discussion before about the current trend to drop the Saxon genitive in associative rather than possessive / 'of' structures. _The writers' day was spent at the Writers Guild._

Answer (score 1):

It's "three days' work" because of the fact that there are three days. As this is a plural, the apostrophe comes after "s" to distinguish it from a singular, which has the apostrophe come *before* the "s":

> The cat's fur/ singular
>
> The cats' meows/ plural

Comment: Or even "The cat's fur/ singular" and "The cats' fur/ plural".

Comment: You got it! :) :)

Comment: not to mention the cat's meows (single cat, plural meows)

Comment: Or the cat's litters' mess

Answer (score 0):

The second option, 'three days' work' is correct. Standard possessive form for a plural.

The construction is used to relate value of the work and the time spent on that work. "I did three days' work in two [days]" is an example. "I did a thousand dollars' work but was paid five hundred" follows the same pattern.

The standard possessive construction is used. The item being possessed is the implied value.