# 24-hours notice vs. 24-hour's notice vs. 24-hours' notice

Tags: phrases, apostrophe, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Phrasing “An hour's rest”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54460/phrasing-an-hours-rest)

In the sentence
"You must provide 24-hours notice."

which is correct:

1. 24-hours notice
2. 24-hour's notice
3. 24-hours' notice