# Winter('?)s first snow

Tags: orthography, apostrophe

I'm having a hard time deciding if these get apostrophes.

> 1. The beauty of winters first snow.
> 2. The days final light.

If either or both need the apostrophe, where should I place it, and why?

Comment: Related: **1** [Is it correct to use an apostrophe to indicate something that belongs to an object?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207598/is-it-correct-to-use-an-apostrophe-to-indicate-something-that-belongs-to-an-obje)  **2** [Is using the possessive 's correct in “the car's antenna”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/is-using-the-possessive-s-correct-in-the-cars-antenna)  **3**. [“The dog's tail” vs. “the tail of the dog”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88389/the-dogs-tail-vs-the-tail-of-the-dog)

Comment: Also related: **4** [Should “two weeks vacation” be written “two weeks’ vacation” with a possessive apostrophe?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103849/should-two-weeks-vacation-be-written-two-weeks-vacation-with-a-possessive-a) **5** [Phrasing “An hour's rest”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54460/phrasing-an-hours-rest) **6** [Where should the apostrophe go in “three days work”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29220/where-should-the-apostrophe-go-in-three-days-work)

Answer (score 3):

The possessive apostrophe is required in both cases; the *snow* and the *light* belong to “winter” and  “day” respectively. The apostrophe  goes before the -s.

> 1. The beauty of winter's first snow.
> 2. The day's final light.

If days were meant to be plural, the possessive apostrophe should come after the -s, however, I would also recommend adding an adjective, or any qualifier, before the noun just to clarify.

> 2. The autumn days' final light.
> 3. The final light of autumn's days. (paraphrased)