# "2 hours' worth" or "2 hours worth"?

Tags: apostrophe, time

I think "1 hour’s worth" is the correct way to write this. Therefore, in the plural case, I assume the correct choice is "2 hours’ worth". Which one is it?

Just wondering because someone [edited a question of mine](https://superuser.com/posts/26308/revisions) to remove these apostrophes.

Comment: Roll that edit back! (And link to here for your edit summary, if asked.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should the apostrophe go in "three days work"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29220/where-should-the-apostrophe-go-in-three-days-work)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600416/2085).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct. There is no logical reason for the number (not case) to be plural with one. It's like saying *a worth of one hour,* so the genitive (aka possessive) case would be correct.

Comment: In what way have I misunderstood?

Comment: Maybe you didn’t misunderstand it, it’s just that this is not about whether it should be singular or plural. Your second sentence addresses only the number, and the last sentence seems to assume singular. But the question is about which case to use in the plural :)

Comment: But I didn't answer whether it should be singular or plural. I answered whether it should be bare or genitive. The use of the singular simplifies things, as the OP clearly realizes.

Comment: OK, then I’m the one who misunderstood :) My apologies :)