# What is the correct grammar for "a days-long wait"

Tags: grammar, possessives, hyphenation

> Surely there's a better way; something instantaneous that doesn't involve a days-long wait?

Is the grammar above correct? Particularly, should 'days-long' be hyphenated, and should it contain a [possessive apostrophe](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/29221/347162)? Note: "days" in the above is strictly plural e.g. 7-10 days

Comment: Although I can only find the standard adjective  _daylong_ in dictionaries, there are many examples on the internet of the form 'a days-long event/competition/search ...'. No apostrophe, as per 'daylong'.

Comment: The hyphen is correct, but the construction is clunky. Perhaps: *Surely there's a better way—something instantaneous that doesn't involve days of waiting.*