# Should "years worth" have an apostrophe?

Tags: grammar

Maybe this is a dumb question.  If I was writing the sentence "following years worth of research...", would it be correct to write "years worth" or "years' worth"?

My initial instinct was "years worth", but MS Word's autocorrect is flagging that as incorrect.  I've thought about this for almost a week but am still not sure which is correct, to be completely honest.

Thanks.

Comment: You should do a few minutes' worth of research online. I'm sure you can find hundreds of examples.

Comment: @Laurel IMO https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29220/where-if-anywhere-should-the-apostrophe-go-in-three-days-work , which the question you linked is suggested to be a duplicate of, is a better precedent (better answer, anyway!)

Comment: You can avoid the question with *following years of research*.